# uploaded images only show some thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am trying to show thumbnail images with an input field next to them when they are uploaded to the server. problem is my function is trying to show the images before they are uploaded.

I think this has to do with calling the thumbnails before they exist on the server. Is there a way to change my code to call the images to be show after the are done uploading to the server?

Here is my HTML

```
  <div class="module">
            <div class="moduleTitle">Upload Photos</div>            
                   <form id="upload" method="post" action="actions/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" id="username">
            <div id="drop">
                Drop Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>


            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>
                 </form>
            </div>

             <div class="module">
            <div class="moduleTitle">Add Tags to Images</div> 
            <form onSubmit="addTags();return false;" id="tagAddForm">
            <ul>
        <!-- Ths is where the tag inputs will appear -->
        </ul>
             <input type="submit" name="login" value="Add Tags" class="submit" id="login"/>
           </form>
        </div>
```

Here is my JS

```
$(function(){

    var ul = $('#upload ul'); 
;;

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {



       var tpl = $('<li class="working uploaded"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');


            // Append the file name and file size      
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name);


            //Create an empty container
            var path = "artistpit/users/" + $("#username").val() + "/";
            var $elems = $();
            //Cycle thru the files
            $.each(data.files, function(idx, file) {
                //Create an input with attrsd
                var $input = $("<input/>", {
                    'type': 'text',
                    'placeholder': 'separate tags with commas',
                    'name': file["name"]
                });
                //Create list element with an image thumb + append input
                var $li = $("<li/>", {
                html: "<img src='" + path + file["name"] + "' width='50' />"
                }).append($input);
                //Populate the container with the list item
                $elems = $elems.add($li);
            });
            //Append all list items
            $("#tagAddForm > UL").append($elems); 




            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },

        progress: function(e, data){

            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
            // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
            data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

            if(progress == 100){
                data.context.removeClass('working');
            }
        },

        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }

    });


    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }



});
```

Comment: could you please post your HTML as well?

Comment: I did it just for you :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your problem could be solved if you don't add to the `DOM` the thumbnails after update finish.

Try adding the elements at the callback of upload. I add a callback for the submit() option.

```
$(function(){

    var ul = $('#upload ul'); 
;;

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {



       var tpl = $('<li class="working uploaded"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');


            // Append the file name and file size      
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name);


            //Create an empty container
            var path = "artistpit/users/" + $("#username").val() + "/";
            var $elems = $();
            //Cycle thru the files
            $.each(data.files, function(idx, file) {
                //Create an input with attrsd
                var $input = $("<input/>", {
                    'type': 'text',
                    'placeholder': 'separate tags with commas',
                    'name': file["name"]
                });
                //Create list element with an image thumb + append input
                var $li = $("<li/>", {
                html: "<img src='" + path + file["name"] + "' width='50' />"
                }).append($input);
                //Populate the container with the list item
                $elems = $elems.add($li);
            });    


            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit().success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR){
                //Append all list items
                $("#tagAddForm > UL").append($elems);
            });
        },

        progress: function(e, data){

            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
            // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
            data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

            if(progress == 100){
                data.context.removeClass('working');
            }
        },

        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }

    });


    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }



});
```

Comment: this caused error.   $("#tagAddForm > UL").append($elems); in the console it users/nichodiaz/IMG_3666.JPG 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I'm assuming that the src you establish on the img is in fact correct. If that src isn't right I cannot do anything. Anyway I move the appended items on success callback of `data.submit()`. Check it out.

Comment: now i get this Uncaught ReferenceError: $input is not defined

Comment: That error has nothing to do with my answer. That's another problem related with the code provided. I just added a `success` callback at `submit()` function and moved a sentence in it. I'll try to solve that too, wich line is giving that error? Maybe you could try to rename the `$input` variable with another name like `tag_input` or something? just in case.